# Mysql complement with many tables and grouping

Tags: mysql, complement

I hope the answer is simple and I'm silly.

So I've two tables: `day` (with PK `id_day`) and `hour` (with PK `id_hour`).

I've an another table `tilt_time` which has `id_day`, `id_hour` fields and a plus FK field (which has prohibited times). E.g. `tilt_time` has the following rows (`id_day`, `id_hour`, `id_target`):

```
1,1,1
1,2,1
1,3,1
1,1,2
1,2,2
```

In table `day` `id_day` is between 1 and 5 (monday to friday) and `hour` `id_hour` is between 1 and 6 (so you can imagine a `day_hour` table with 5*6=30 values).

So I want query `id_target=1`'s free periods and `id_target=2`'s free periods (everbody's free periods). So I want similar:

```
1,4,1
1,5,1
1,6,1
2,*,1
3,*,1
4,*,1
5,*,1
// id_target=2
1,3,2
1,4,2
1,5,2
1,6,2
2,*,2
3,*,2
4,*,2
5,*,2
```

(* means all valid `id_hour` values, so every line with * represents 6 different lines)

How can I do this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `target` table with all `id_target`, the answer is simple:

```
SELECT 
    d.id_day, h.id_hour, t.id_target
FROM 
    day AS d
  CROSS JOIN
    hour AS h
  CROSS JOIN
    target AS t
WHERE
    (d.id_day, h.id_hour, t.id_target) NOT IN
      ( SELECT id_day, id_hour, id_target
        FROM tilt_time
      )
;
```

or the (probably more efficient):

```
SELECT 
    d.id_day, h.id_hour, t.id_target
FROM 
    day AS d
  CROSS JOIN
    hour AS h
  CROSS JOIN
    target AS t
  LEFT JOIN
    tilt_time AS tt
      ON  tt.id         = d.id_day
      AND tt.id_hour    = h.id_hour
      AND t.t.id_target = t.id_target
WHERE 
    tt.id_target iS NULL ;
```

---

If you don't have a `target` table, replace the `target AS t` in the code above with:

```
( SELECT DISTINCT id_target FROM tilt_time ) AS t
```

Comment: Wow :) It's too simple :) I need some modifications but almost perfect! Thanks!

Comment: "If you don't have a target table, replace the target AS t in the code above with" - I did this modification before your edit because I need only those targets which are in `tilt_time`.

Answer (score 0):

The following query returns `id_day` and `id_hour` in which both target ids of 1 and 2 have no record in `tilt_time`.

```
SELECT tg1_free.id_day, tg2_free.id_hour
FROM (
    SELECT
        day.id_day, hour.id_hour
    FROM day, hour
    WHERE
        (day.id_day, hour.id_hour) NOT IN (SELECT id_day, id_hour FROM tilt_time WHERE id_target = 1)
) tg1_free
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        day.id_day, hour.id_hour
    FROM day, hour
    WHERE
        (day.id_day, hour.id_hour) NOT IN (SELECT id_day, id_hour FROM tilt_time WHERE id_target = 2)
) tg2_free ON (tg1_free.id_day = tg2_free.id_day AND tg1_free.id_hour = tg2_free.id_hour)
```

[EDIT]

For all of target ids there is (it's even easier):

```
SELECT id_day, id_hour
FROM day, hour
WHERE
    (day.id_day, hour.id_hour) NOT IN (SELECT id_day, id_hour FROM tilt_time);
```

Comment: Sorry, but the two `id_target` isn't enough. I need all `id_target` (I've wrote: "everbody's free periods"). Can you modify your answer?
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry again :) My english is poor. I want all free time PER `id_target` not free times without `id_target`.

Comment: Then you just need to include your id_target in subquery's where clause